# VxWorks CF creatred with dosFsVolFormat cannot be read on Windows

Tags: windows, vxworks

I have an embedded VxWorks application that formats a Compact Flash using 'dosFsVolFormat' and then writes data to the CF. When I take the CF out and try to read it in any Windows PC all the machines do not recognize it.

I've tried the following windows version machines: Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 10.

I've installed Cygwin and do a 'dd' to copy a binary image to a disk but that really defeats the purpose of the dosFsVolFormat().

I need to grap the data from CF and put it into word/spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: PS Formatting the CF in a windows machine first then putting it into the embedded device to let it do it's data gathering is not an option.

Comment: What version of VxWorks are you using? The VxWorks FAT file system code has had many bug fixes between 6.8 through 6.9.

Comment: Tornado 2.2. I'm wondering, being this is just an old version maybe the FAT format they are using is not readable by new window OSs, e.g. 7 and up.

Comment: If you're using tornado you're probably using a very old version of vxWorks. You need to find your vxWorks version by looking up the version.h file in your vxWorks installation directory. Then go look up all the bugs they've fixed in the FAT file system libraries. I'd bet that the bug your seeing was already fixed in a newer version of vxWorks.

Comment: Ah sorry you asked VxWorks, version, 5.5. Even if they did fix an issue it will not help me. I have to stay with this version and tornado. Old legacy code. And this 'data' has been read in the past. Just that knowledge is gone and I am trying to recreate it.

Comment: PS I can alter the code, I just cannot update the VxWork version.

Comment: What are the flags that are being passed in dosFsVolFormat? I hope DOS_OPT_VXLONGNAMES is not being set.

Comment: No DOS_OPT_VXLONGNAMES, using DOS_OPT_FAT32 and DOS_OPT_QUIET.

Comment: As per vxworks documentation, they recommended that any
 disks which are expected to be interchanged between vxWorks and
 Windows should be formatted under Windows to provide the best
 interchangeability.  The WRS implementation is more flexible,
 and should be able to handle the differences when formatting is
 done on Windows, but Windows implementations may not be able to
handle minor differences between their implementation and ours. Can you try the same?